# Can't restart PHP with homebrew on macOS

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macos-monterey

I successfully installed homebrew by following the instructions of the official website (https://brew.sh/).

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

It was installed under /opt/homebrew
I then did install php with `brew install php@8.1`

If I restart php with `brew services restart php` I get the following error message:

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/USER/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
```

I use macOS Monterey 12.4

Using sudo to restart php results in the warning:

`Warning: php must be run as non-root to start at user login!`

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: try to run your terminal as an administrator?

Answer (score 12):

Command to restart my php-fpm:

`brew services restart php@8.1`

If you don't have brew services, try installing it like this:

`brew tap homebrew/services`

Comment: I already tried restarting like this. Specifying the php version didn't help. I do have brew services.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Solved by using 'chown' on a sub directory that was still running under the wrong user.